# s3 object as corpus_file for gensim Doc2Vec

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, aws

Is it possible to use a txt or jsonl file in an s3 bucket as the `corpus_file` input for a gensim Doc2Vec model? I am looking for something of the form:

```
Doc2Vec(corpus_file="s3://bucket_name/subdir/sample.jsonl")
```

When I run the above line, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Parameter corpus_file must be a valid path to a file, got 's3://bucket_name/subdir/sample.jsonl' instead.
```

I have also tried creating an iterator object that iterates through the file and yields its lines, and passing it as the `corpus_file` argument. But I get the same TypeError.

Please note that I am specifically looking to use the `corpus_file` argument instead of the `documents` for possible performance gain.